# Stop DataGridView from flowing under panel?

Tags: c#, css, winforms, datagridview

### Question

How can I stop my datagridview from moving underneath the panel when the window is resized?

### Example

[image]

### What I have tried? And what I would like.

- I have tried to dock the datagridview to the top on the window, but it just docks under the panel.
- I have tried docking both to the top and docking one to the top and the other to the bottom, however they both just take half the screen up.

*What I would like is if the datagridview docked to the bottom of the panel.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the `Anchor` property on your controls.  Based on what you've provided, the `DataGridView` control is probably anchored `Bottom, Right`, and you should anchor it `Top, Left` to match what the panel control's anchor is.

Also, if you *do* want the grid to be anchored to the bottom, right, you can set the `MinimumSize` property of your form accordingly so that it can never be resized such that the controls "collide".

It's not possible without third-party controls to dock one control to another control.